# Strange behavior of \color over pages

Tags: color

When I run the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={4in, 3in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\let\old@makefntext\@makefntext
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\old@makefntext{{\color{green}#1}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
a \vspace{1.5in}

a\footnote{a\\a}

{\color{red} a} a
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:
[image]

Two strange things happen: (i) no coloring of the second `a` in the `footnote` (ii) color reversal of two `a`'s on the second page.

This should have something to do with redefining the footnote, but I don't know why (maybe `colorstack`?)
For some reason, I need to redefine `\@makefntext` in this way, and I would like to know how to handle this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure you can save the color in split footnotes. Anyway, you can at least fix the coloring in the second page using `\textcolor{red}{a}` instead of `{\color{red}a}` (which is wrong in this context).

Comment: use `{\leavevmode\color{red}a}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the package `pdfcolfoot`. Everything then works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={4in, 3in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{pdfcolfoot}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@footnotetext}[1]{%
  \insert\footins{\reset@font\footnotesize%
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty%
    \splittopskip\footnotesep%
    \splitmaxdepth\dp\strutbox%
    \floatingpenalty\@MM%
    \hsize\columnwidth%
    \@parboxrestore%
    \def\@currentcounter{footnote}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{\color{green}% <-- color set to green
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces #1\@finalstrut\strutbox}\par
    \color@endgroup}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
a \vspace{1.5in}

a\footnote{a\\ a}

{\color{red} a} a
\end{document}
```